# $i_{\ast}\widetilde{M_0}$ and $\widetilde{M}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $I$ be an ideal of $R$.  Let $Z = \textrm{Spec}(R/I), X = \textrm{Spec}(R)$, and let $i: Z \rightarrow X$ be the closed immersion corresponding to the ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow R/I$.

Suppose that $M$ is a module over $R$ which is annihilated by $I$.  Then $M$ is well defined as an $R/I$-module.  When we think of $M$ as an $R/I$-module, rather than an $R$-module, let's call it $M_0$.

Let $\widetilde{M}$ be the sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules corresponding to $M$, and let $\widetilde{M_0}$ be the sheaf of $\mathcal O_Z$-modules corresponding to $M_0$.  We recover

$$\widetilde{M}(X) = M = M_0 = \widetilde{M_0}(Z)$$

Since $\widetilde{M_0}$ is a sheaf of abelian groups on a closed set $Z$ in $X$, we can extend it by zero to a sheaf $i_{\ast} \widetilde{M_0}$ of abelian groups on $X$ whose stalks at all $x \in X - Z$ are zero.  Since $\widetilde{M_0}$ is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_Z$-modules, $i_{\ast}\widetilde{M_0}$ is a sheaf of $i_{\ast} \mathcal O_Z = \mathcal O_X/ \textrm{Ker}(i^{\#})$-modules.

What, in general, is the connection between $i_{\ast}\widetilde{M_0}$ and $\tilde{M}$?  Does $i_{\ast} \widetilde{M_0}$ come from an $R$-module at all?

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{Ker}(i^{\#}) = I^{\sim}$ and $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z = (R/I)^{\sim}$; furthermore, it's natural to consider $i_*\widetilde{M_0}$ as an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module through the ring map $R\to R/I$, or rather $i^{\#}\colon \mathcal{O}_X\to i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$. Then $i_*\widetilde{M_0} = \widetilde{M}$. Is this what you're asking?